# in my printer, paper is skipping too much

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printers, dot-matrix

Am using the 80 column dot matric printer ,

For every print , paper gets skip two time, too much of papers going waste ,

How to fix this problem ,

Am just using the

```
   window.print()
```

javascript function

is there any setting available to avoid the paper wastage ,

Any idea

Comment: Voting to close, I can't see this as a programming issue.

Comment: no , actually is there any way with program , to stop paper skip

Comment: this is more a printer configuration issue

Comment: Actually, there are steps you can take to make your site print-friendly, if we're talking about a specific site, and not a specific printer...

Comment: You can't program a printer using JavaScript.

Comment: By closing this question you've doomed Earth to an arid wasteland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on "Print Preview" in your browser and make sure your site look reasonable. If it is, it's a printer settings, and not much you can do about it. If it doesn't look well on the preview, you can set a [printing-specific CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) and correct it by reducing margins, or changing colors (for example, you may have a large element with `background-image` that will take space but will not be printed).